# The content of 'sequence' must match annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence | any)*)

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I keep getting this error:

> The content of 'sequence' must match annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence | any)*). A problem was found starting at: simpleType. The xsd has to include an example of custom named simpleType.

I was trying to include that example but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<famous_landmarks>
    <landmark>
        <name language="English">St Basil&apos;s Cathedral</name>
        <name language="Russian">собо́р Васи́лия Блаже́нного</name>
        <location>Moscow, Russia</location>
        <height unit="feet">156</height>
        <year_built>1561</year_built>
    </landmark>
    <landmark>
        <name language="English">St Peter&apos;s Cathedral</name>
        <name language="Latin">Basilica Sancti Petri</name>
        <location>Vatican City</location>
        <!-- It is an independent city-state enclaved within Rome, Italy -->
        <height unit="feet">448</height>
        <year_built>1626</year_built>
    </landmark>
    <landmark>
        <name language="English">Christ the Redeemer</name>
        <name language="Portuguese">Cristo Redentor</name>
        <location>Rio de Janeiro, Brazil</location>
        <height unit="feet">125</height>
        <year_built>1931</year_built>
    </landmark>
    <landmark>
        <name language="English">Hagia Sophia</name>
        <name language="Greek">Αγία Σοφία</name>
        <!-- Originally a cathedral, it was converted into a mosque and then a museum -->
        <location>Istanbul, Turkey</location>
        <height unit="feet">180</height>
        <year_built>537</year_built>
        <image file="hagiasophia.png"/>
    </landmark>
    <landmark>
        <name language="English">Brandenburg Gate</name>
        <name language="German">Brandenburger Tor</name>
        <location>Berlin, Germany</location>
        <height unit="feet">85</height>
        <year_built>1791</year_built>
    </landmark>
    <landmark>
        <name language="English">Neuschwanstein Castle</name>
        <name language="German">Schloss Neuschwanstein</name>
        <location>Hohenschwangau, Germany</location>
        <height unit="feet">213</height>
        <year_built>1886</year_built>
    </landmark>
    <landmark>
        <name language="English">Dome of the Rock</name>
        <name language="Arabic">Qubbat al-Sakhrahة‎</name>
        <location>Jerusalem, Israel</location>
        <height unit="feet">115</height>
        <year_built>692</year_built>
    </landmark>
    <landmark>
        <name language="English">Statue of Liberty</name>
        <location>New York City, United States</location>
        <height unit="feet">305</height>
        <year_built>1886</year_built>
    </landmark>
    <landmark>
        <name language="English">Big Ben</name>
        <location>London, England</location>
        <height unit="feet">315</height>
        <year_built>1859</year_built>
    </landmark>
    <landmark>
        <name language="English"> Angel of Independence</name>
        <name language="Spanish">Monumento a la Independencia</name>
        <location>Mexico City, Mexico</location>
        <height unit="feet">148</height>
        <year_built>1910</year_built>
    </landmark>
</famous_landmarks>
```

This is my xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="www.famouslandmarks.com" targetNamespace="www.famouslandmarks.com">
    <xs:element name="famous_landmarks">
        <!--feature 2: complex type element containing child elements-->
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <!--feature 6: required attribute-->
                        <xs:attribute name="language" use="required">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <!--feature 8: specification of a set of acceptable values-->
                                    <xs:enumeration value="English" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Arabic" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="German" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Greek" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Latin" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Portuguese" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Russian" />
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Spanish" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <!--feature 3: named custom simple type-->
                <xs:simpleType name="location_type">
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
                </xs:simpleType>
                <xs:element name="location" type="location_type" />
                <!--feature 9: specification of minimum and maximum number of occurrences-->
                <xs:element name="height" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <!--feature 4: non-string data type-->
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                            <!--feature 7: range of acceptable values-->
                            <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                            <xs:maxInclusive value="448" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <!--feature 1: simple type element -->
                <xs:element name="year_built" type="xs:gYear" />
                <!--feature 5: "fixed" attribute-->
                <xs:element name="era" type="xs:string" fixed="AD" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm at my wits end and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message actually points quite clearly to the problem...but only if you know how to read XML Schema error messages.

The error message is saying that within a sequence, only certain types of child object are allowed. They are: an element, a group reference, a choice group, a sequence group or an xs:any. Each of those can optionally have a schema annotation.

Armed with that information, it should now be obvious where your problem is. Your xs:sequence contains a simple type declaration, which is not allowed.

There are two ways to fix the problem

1. Move the xs:simpleType to the top level of the schema (so that it is a sibling of element declaration 'famous landmarks'). Do this if location_type is used by more than one element.
2. Remove the 'name' attribute from the xs:simpleType declaration and make it a *child* of element declaration 'location'. You should also remove the 'type' attribute from 'location' as there will be no global simple type with name 'location_type'. Do this if location_type will only ever be used by this element declaration.